# Dynamic form builder in php

Tags: php, mysql

Do we have any dynamic form builder in php? I am creating a dynamic form builder in PHP, I will store the fields in the database and they will be rendered in a form dynamically from database.

I wanted to know if there is any existing api that does so?

Comment: have you find any?

Comment: nope, developed it in laravel for a project @AliRaza

Answer (score 0):

You can try use Symfony2 Forms. If I remember correctly this module should be separated from other parts of S2 or need a small piece.

Comment: that's tightly coupled, I need the core api independent of frameworks so that I can use the objects in any framework